# How to close modal dialog in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to close the jquery dialog on click of a button which is placed in that dialog how should i do this?

Comment: ? What are you using jQuery-UI some jQuery modal dialog plugin in what? Without more info we can't answer this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using [jquery ui dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/):

```
$('#foo').dialog('close');
```

Where `foo` is the id of the DOM element the dialog has been attached to.

Answer (score 0):

Assumed that you created the dialog this way, using JQuery UI:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({...});
```

( A Dom element with ID = "dialog" )

You can close this dialog by inserting this line of code into your button click action:

```
$("#dialog").dialog("close");
```

P.S.
You must write additional info, as other users suggested before.